# How do you preview a local video file on a website without a backend?

Tags: javascript, html, web, html5-video, frontend

Is it possible to create a URL that hosts a local image file using `URL.createObjectURL(fileName)` and from there, you can just drop that URL in an `img` tag.
How would you do something similar, but for video files, so that you could preview video files on a website before sending it to the backend?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like,

```
$(document).on("change", ".file_video", function(evt) {
  var $source = $('#video_here');
  $source[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  $source.parent()[0].load();
})
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video width="500" controls>
  <source src="my_video.mp4" id="video_here">
</video>

<input type="file" name="file[]" class="file_video" accept="video/*">
```

You can get more details from here [get in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035721/how-can-i-set-preview-of-video-file-selecting-from-input-type-file/40580663)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
file:///C:/my/path/video.mpg
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details?