# Bootstrap image/video upload and preview

Tags: javascript, php, html, api, bootstrap-4

Hi we are making a website at the moment using a bootstrap template. Database driven. Javascript, php etc.

We are wondering would anyone know a good solution to a problem we are facing.

We are going to be an advertising platform. We have a post ad section which is in 3 steps.

1. Input data.
2. Upload images.
3. Preview advert.

With the media showing as 1 large image along with x number of images below as clickable thumbnails.

This is fine but weve noticed our solution seems to resize the image in order to fit it into the area, rather than keeping its ratio.

Now that we have noticed this there has been other things which have annoyed us about our solution, mainly having no video upload + play.

I'm wondering does anyone know of a good solution to this they could recommend?

Answer (score 0):

> "This is fine but weve noticed our solution seems to resize the image in order to fit it into the area, rather than keeping its ratio."
>   for this you will need a little CSS the container of the image should have a fixed width while the image a full width of 100% eg

```
<div class="container"><img class="img-fluid" src="myimage.jpg" /></div>
```

here "img-fluid" is the (width-100) class it could be "img-responsive" on older bootstrap versions

> Now that we have noticed this there has been other things which have annoyed us about our solution, mainly having no video upload + play

View this soulution here [video embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035721/how-can-i-set-preview-of-video-file-selecting-from-input-type-file/40580663)

hope this helps